# Is there a user interface in Emacs allowing one to "grab" the buffer's filename conveniently?

Tags: emacs, filenames, copy-paste

It happens quite often that I want to use the path of the file opened in a certain buffer in Emacs (either the full path or the basename) in another place (a buffer or a different X program, say, a terminal). I wonder whether there is some pre-defined subsystem in the Emacs "user interface" that would copy the filename of the current buffer (`(buffer-file-name)`) to the kill-ring.

Related things: There is a simple command in emacs-w3m that does an analoguos thing (<kbd>y</kbd> -- `w3m-print-current-url`): it prints the URL and copies it to the kill-ring.

Of course, I could simply define the command I want, but I'm asking this question because I hope to learn some user interface subsystem of Emacs that includes such a possibility among other features. (Perhaps, some buffer and path manipulation interfaces.) So that I will know more useful features of Emacs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I do this:

1. <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-v</kbd> (find-alternate-file)
2. <kbd>C-a</kbd> (move-beginning-of-line)
3. <kbd>C-k</kbd> (kill-line)
4. <kbd>C-g</kbd> (keyboard-quit)

It's quicker than using the minibuffer history.  If all you want is the base name, it's even faster - just skip the <kbd>C-a</kbd> in the second step.

Comment: Thank you! I've checked that `find-alternate-file` in my Emacs works indeed this way, but since I have setup it to use ffap and `C-x C-v` is bound to `ffap-alternate-file`, this doesn't work for me. (Pressing down in the prompt of my `C-x C-v` also brings up the current file name.)

Comment: Awesome, it works on my emacs 24! It would be great if someone wrap s these things in a command.

Comment: @TruongHa Yeah, the other solution (the answer below) stopped working in Emacs 24 for me....

Comment: @imz--IvanZakharyaschev, replacing `<down>` with `M-n` may be more ergonomic.

Answer (score 2):

The quickest way to copy the name of the current file in the default setup is

```
C-x C-f             find-file
down                next-history-element
C-SPC C-a M-w       select and copy the minibuffer contents
C-g                 abort find-file
```

Comment: Great! I have learned something indeed, as I hoped. Before, I had no idea that pressing "down" in the minibuffer (when selecting a file) would bring the current buffer's filename into the field.

Comment: I should have read the documentation for `find-file` more carefully: "... the visited file name is available through the minibuffer history:
type M-n to pull it into the minibuffer."!

Comment: [Teddy's solution](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/12939#12939) is much nicer than mine. I didn't know `C-x C-v` pre-filled the file name, and `C-k` is a lot quicker to kill the whole line (I should have thought of that). @imz: please accept Teddy's answer, and I'll delete mine.

Comment: Actually, I don't like the idea of deleting an answer (the yours one or whatever different answer I'll get here in the future) if it works correctly, because it teaches us (at least, me) something new about the features of Emacs. I think this is much more important than just getting one quickest way to "grab" the filename. Please don't delete your answer!

Comment: @imz: Ok, then please accept his answer (for people who just want the answer to your question, it should be displayed first) and I'll leave mine up.

Comment: Hmm, this stopped working in Emacs 24 for C-x C-f! The accepted answer (with C-x C-v) still works. I wonder why they have removed this feature of `find-file`....

Comment: @imz--IvanZakharyaschev Which version removed this? It does work in 24.3.

Comment: @Gilles--Yes, you are correct. On another machine of mine, Emacs 24.3 has this feature. I haven't customized these things. So probably that's because some of the standard elisp libraries are not present on that machine where this doesn't work... My distro (ALT) has split all Emacs into several packages. I'll have a look now...

Comment: @Gilles--The problem where C-x C-f DOWN doesn't work is reported in `*Messages*`: byte-code: Cannot open load file: auth-source

Comment: @Gilles--And `/usr/share/emacs/24.3/lisp/gnus/auth-source.elc` is from Gnus, which was put into a separate package. No idea why C-x C-f DOWN needs something from Gnus.

Comment: @imz--IvanZakharyaschev It doesn't. You must have something hooking into or replacing `find-file`.