# How to get current buffer's filename in emacs?

Tags: emacs, function

One of the main features I miss about Vim, is that it always saves the filename of the current file in the `%` buffer ([more info](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Get_the_name_of_the_current_file)). That allows launching commands easily like:

```
;; compile current file
:! gcc %
;; source current file (useful when I'm editing .vimrc
:source %
;; get the size of current file
:! du -sh %
;; etc, etc...
```

I would like to have similar functionality under `emacs` (version 24, if that makes any difference), namely have an easy way to insert the name of the file opened in the current buffer.

**Examples of what I want to do**

*Here I describe some basic use cases as to explain better when I feel the need for such a shortcut*

1. Compile: When I enter `M-x compile` emacs asks me for a compile command. I would like to enter `gcc (current-buffer)` easily.
2. Load-file: When I'm editing my .emacs file, I would like to load it right away to test the changes. The way I do it is `M-x load-file` and then I always spell out the name <kbd>.</kbd> <kbd>e</kbd> <kbd>m</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>s</kbd>. I would like to have a shortcut.
3. Launch outside processes: I gave `du -sh` as an example, only to illustrate that I want the shortcut to be also available when I execute shell commands with `M-!`

**What I found so far**

- [This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/9738/4098) here on U&L. The answers given are basically showing where to find the filename of a buffer so one can add it to the kill-ring. It's not exactly what I'm looking for, I don't want to have to manually kill the filename before I want to use it. (Also solutions described in both answers don't seem to work as smoothly in my emacs and require additional keystrokes making them a bit of a pain).

***EDIT***: A bit unrelated, by I found out why these solutions don't work. I have IDO enabled, for better or worse.

- The `(current-buffer)` function [described in the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Current-Buffer.html) does return the name of the file in the current buffer, but nowhere in the examples I gave above, am I evaluating elisp code. Is there a way to insert the result of the evaluation of this function in a (mini)buffer and binding this way to a shortcut?

**Am I wrong to think this way?**

I am currently learning to use emacs (it's been a few months actually) after years of using Vim. I want to avoid a predictable *using-emacs-in-a-Vim-way* trap. If you feel that what I'm asking for is not very *emacs-y*, and there should be a better (cleaner?) way to do it, please do mention it in your answers.

Comment: About filename, in .emacs, put `(global-set-key (kbd "C-i") buffer-file-name)` if you'd like it to be Ctrl+I. About .emacs, `M-x load-file RET` does what you want; you don't need to write anything.

Comment: This workflow doesn't mesh with Emacs very well, because all the prompts on the bottom line of the window are in a buffer in Emacs (called a minibuffer). So if you run `(buffer-file-name)` while you're typing in the minibuffer, you get `nil`, because `(current-buffer)` is the minibuffer. You can switch buffers while in the minibuffer, too, so it's hard to keep track of which buffer is what you think of the current buffer by the time the current buffer, as Emacs sees it, is the minibuffer.

Answer (score 15):

You can put a function like follows into your `.emacs` and bind it to any key you like.

```lisp
(defun insert-file-name ()
  "Insert the full path file name into the current buffer."
  (interactive)
  (insert (buffer-file-name (window-buffer (minibuffer-selected-window)))))
```

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455345/in-emacs-how-to-insert-file-name-in-shell-command), it seems to be similar.

Answer (score 6):

A slight variant on [@easyb's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/45381/208146) answer is to copy the path to your kill ring instead of placing it into your buffer (useful for read only files):

```lisp
(defun filename ()   
    "Copy the full path of the current buffer."  
    (interactive)  
    (kill-new (buffer-file-name (window-buffer (minibuffer-selected-window)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

`(kill-new buffer-filename)` seems to be sufficient if you bind it to a key like this - I added this line in my `~/.emacs.d/init.el` :

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c w") (lambda () (interactive) (kill-new buffer-file-name)))
```

Whenever I want to put the current filename in the kill buffer, I just press `C-c w`, then use the usual `C-y` wherever I want to yank it.

Comment: `M-: (kill-new buffer-file-name)`